# Is it possible to use HDMI cable to transfer files between notebooks?

Tags: hdmi, file-transfer, bandwidth

HDMI 1.3 bandwidth is over 10G.  Notebook nowadays has HDMI port available.  Is that possible that we use HDMI cable to hook up 2 notebook and perform file copy operation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's technically possible, as HDMI is a bidirectional interface. however, it is designed for packet streams, and not data blocks.

So, in a practical sense, from a users perspective: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Yeah... It's *possible*, but you'd have to do some pretty low-level hacking (possibly even writing custom drivers?) to pull it off.

Comment: HDMI does potentially provide an Ethernet channel so that internet-enabled home theater equipment can have a one-cable solution (http://www.hdmi.org/manufacturer/hdmi_1_4/hec.aspx) but Ethernet over HDMI doesn't even come close to the available bandwidth of the HDMI interface.

Comment: @Stephanie I believe this is due to wrapping Ethernet packets into HDMI packets. When lengths are not equal, they'd have to be split and rearrange, possibly buffered. I's just assumptions, though. I don't think that that kind of equipment comes with TCP stacks, it's probably implemented in firmware...

Comment: I too am interested in this. This is the highest bandwidth interface easily available to the consumer.

Comment: what do you mean by packet streams? how would this be a drawback more specifically?..

Comment: @CorneliuZuzu streams like bitstreams, similar to how you use RTP/RTCP for streaming media over Ethernet. HDMI provides Ethernet encapsulation which should technically work well with things like that. Regular TCP/IP connections constantly move blocks back and forth, and I don't think that the Ethernet implementation on HDMI really would work with that.

Comment: today they use hdmi to capture raw video from camera. So "*technically* possible" is true

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't practically help you, but apparently HDMI is being used to stack switches now:

"2 Stacking Ports (HDMI)"

Source: http://www.dell.com/us/fedgov/p/data-center-gigabit/product-compare

Comment: Just to let you know I shamelessly copied one of your blog posts in my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/591208/151431).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, there are HDMI cables that support data, or  even "internet"  sharing. Both devices must have support for data transfer.

Comment: Citation needed.

Answer (score 0):

No its not currently possible to do that, HDMI (High Definition Multimedia Interface) is for video & audio streams only

Answer (score 0):

No. HDMI is a media cable only.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you *could* encode said data into some form of media (audio, video, ) and transfer it through the HDMI and decode it on the target computer.

But it’d be much easier to upload the file to the cloud (Google drive, Dropbox, etc) and download it on the target computer.

Comment: Can the HDMI ports on notebooks *receive* media signals in a way that is accessible to the end-user (or developer), then?

Comment: .. so a Raspberry would output to a laptop screen?

Comment: @weberjn Unless the laptop has been sufficiently modded (custom drivers maybe?), no.