# Upgrade to ubuntu 13.04 from 12.04 with iso image

Tags: linux, upgrade, iso-image, ubuntu-13.04

I have ubuntu 12.04 installed on my system. I want to upgrade it to ubuntu 13.04. I want to do this upgrade using an iso image of ubuntu 13.04.

I tried this [Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39105/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-from-an-iso-image)

But it didn't work for me.

After running these command I didn't get any alerts about updating. Also I don't understand the `gksu` part of the solution.

**Here are the steps I tried:**

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop PATH/TO/ISO /cdrom
```

then

```
sudo /cdrom/cdromupgrade
```

Read more: http://linuxpoison.blogspot.tw/2011/06/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-using-alternate.html#ixzz2SFMqlOPx

I also wanted to know, If I can do this using a networked computer. By this I mean the `iso` file is on some other computer.

Thank you.

Comment: Please include the actual steps you tried, don't make us go look for them in another page. How did it fail? What does "it didn't work for me" mean? Do you now have a broken system?

Comment: I have added the steps I followed for the solution. `It didn't work for me` I mean I didn't get any alert as said in the solution.

Comment: If you have a network, does it have to be done from an ISO?  Couldn't you just `sudo apt dist-upgrade`?

Comment: @Kruug: Yes its a local network(no Internet) and with the helop of iso.

Comment: @Kruug: when I do `sudo apt dist-upgrade` it says `apt command not found` , but with `apt-get` it downloads some packages, thats all.

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps you need to do in order to upgrade from an ISO image are

1. Download the Alternate ISO.
2. [Mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28computing%29) the ISO in the `/media/cdrom` directory. First create the directory if it doesn't exist, then mount the image.

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom  
   sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop PATH/TO/ISO /media/cdrom
   ```

   The solution you posted assumes that as soon as you mount the ISO, it will automatically cause a dialog to appear asking you whether to upgrade. This may or may not happen on your system depending on the Desktop Environment you are using and its [autorun](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/autorun) settings. If it doesn't, launch the upgrader manually as described below.
3. Run the `cdromupgrade` command which is on the ISO, it needs to run with `root` priviledges, so you need `sudo`.

   ```
   sudo /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade
   ```

   or

   ```
   gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
   ```

   `gksu` is a graphical frontend to `su`, it is a just a way of entering your password graphically to get `root` privileges. The two commands are equivalent, they just run `cdromupgrade`.

---

You *can* use a remote ISO but it is probably a better idea to copy it to your local machine, then mount it as described above:

```
scp user@remote.machine:/path/to/source /path/to/target
```

If you *need* to use a remote image, you will still need to mount it locally. I don't know what kind of access you have to the remote server (`ssh`, `ftp`, `nfs`, `smb` etc), so I can't tell you how to mount it locally. If you have `root` access to the local machine you could use `sshfs` and mount the directory containing the ISO:

```
sudo apt-get install fuse-utils sshfs
sudo adduser USER fuse
sshfs user@remote.machine:/path/to/ISO_DIR /local/mount/point
sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop /local/mount/point/Ubuntu.iso /media/cdrom
```

---

Alternatively, you can log on to the remote machine and install from there (copied directly from [here](http://www.kbrandt.com/2008/11/upgrade-ubuntu-remotely.html), the author is [@KyleBrandt](https://superuser.com/users/794/)):

1. Get the [alternate install cd](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/downloadmirrors#alternate).
2. Mount the .iso image or burn it and put it in the cdrom drive: To mount the iso image, first create the /mnt/iso directory with mkdir /mnt/iso and then: `sudo mount ubuntu-8.10-alternate-i386.iso /mnt/iso/
   -t iso9660 -o ro,loop=/dev/loop0`
3. ssh into your remote machine you wish to upgrade: `ssh remote-machine`
   (Optional, but highly recommended): Start a screen session so if you get disconnected it won’t interrupt the upgrade (read how to use screen [here](http://jmcpherson.org/screen.html)): screen
4. Within the screen session, start a text-based cdrom upgrade with the following command: `sudo /mnt/iso/cdromupgrade –frontend=DistUpgradeViewText`
5. The upgrade will periodically ask you yes/no questions throughout the upgrade, so it is not unattended. If you really wanted it to you could try using the yes command and a pipe to force yes to all, but I wouldn’t recommend it and am not sure if it would work:-) One odd thing is if you type ‘d’ for details it opens the information in the program ‘less’, so if you chose this just press ‘q’ to quit after you are done reading the information.