# Can I connect 2 laptops to 1 monitor which has 2 HDMI ports?

Tags: display, hdmi

I am looking at this Dell monitor - Dell U2414H.
Website: http://accessories.ap.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=my&cs=mydhs1&l=en&s=dhs&sku=391-BBNB&redirect=1

Connectivity
***2 HDMI(MHL) connectors***

It says that it has 2 HDMI connectors.

1. Does that mean if I have 2 laptops with HDMI ports, I can connect both the laptops to this 1 single monitor and change input's from the command menu?
2. By connecting the HDMI cable, does that automatically share all the USB devices that is connected to the monitor to my 2 laptops?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can connect the two laptops and use them individually one at a time when you change the monitor inputs.

You cannot -- as far as I know -- transfer data with an HDMI cable, other than display data.

[Is it possible to use HDMI...](https://superuser.com/questions/251713/is-it-possible-to-use-hdmi-cable-to-transfer-files-between-notebooks)

Answer (score 0):

As Dean says, yes you can use two laptops with the one screen and switch between them using the controls on the front panel. This should normally be pretty simple but I don't know that monitor and some can be a pain to switch between inputs.

As for the USB. You cannot access the USB via HDMI. The monitor has 4 downstream and 1 upstream socket. The upstream socket is what you connect to your laptop so without additional hardware, you cannot share the sockets between the laptops.

AFAIK, no current OS supports USB over HDMI. HDMI is primarily designed as a consumer interface for video (it has DRM enforced on it by "Hollywood"). You can however have a network connection over HDMI. DisplayPort and the associated Apple Thunderbolt interfaces are rather more capable and have a number of additional features.

UPDATE: The MHL part of the standard refers to being able to connect non-PC devices such as phones and tablets to the monitor. This works using a special USB to HDMI cable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, definitely. In addition if your notebooks support [HDMI CEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC) there is a chance to change/switch inputs via software ([example](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=15593))
2. I guess USB devices/channels would be bound to selected MHL-ready input device only (no sharing).