# What could I do with the help of HDMI cable between Laptop and Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: hdmi, screen-sharing

I have a Kindle Fire HD with micro-HDMI-port. I also have a Laptop (Lenovo) with macro-HDMI-port.

I am going to buy an HDMI data cable having micro to macro HDMI converter. As it's price is relatively higher than the data cable, I want to know first what could I do with it?

Basically, I want to share my laptop screen in my kindle with sound.

- Is it possible?
- What about the opposite?
- If possible then how to decide which device sharing to whom?
- Is there any extra driver needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to use HDMI cable to transfer files between notebooks?](http://superuser.com/questions/251713/is-it-possible-to-use-hdmi-cable-to-transfer-files-between-notebooks),

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 FYI, I have seen the question before. But there is no clue that it is impossible for Video/Audio stream also. In fact, the question did not ask that. I think, you could understand the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It won't work.

Both of these ports are HDMI outputs and neither can work as an input.

Comment: There is absolutely no way? really?

Comment: @manetsus - There is absolutely no way tomake the Kindle Fire a display for your laptop by connecting it to the HDMI port on the Kindle Fire.

Comment: There actually are some Lenovo laptops with two HDMI sockets, one for input and one for output.